# Ruby: iterate a String and replace characters

Tags: ruby, regex, loops, iterator, gsub

I'm new to ruby and Im trying to iterate through a string to replace repeated characters with a single instance of each. I want to automate the process using an iterator so I dont have to state each character by hand. Example string:

```
u = %q(a a a a a b b b b c c c c)
```

I want the variable u to return String "a b c" after ensuring all repeated characters have been replaced with a single instance of each.

I've tried

```
u.each.scan(/\w+/).join do |x|

 p u.gsub(/\x+/, x)

 end
```

and that wont work.How can I get around this?

Comment: One way you could do this, assuming ' ' is your delimiter is to convert the string to an array, use `uniq`, and then convert back to a string. In your example, `u.split.uniq.join(' ')`.

Comment: Space is a character, too.

Comment: It is not totally clear what your goal is. Should 'a b a' be reduced to 'a b'? Should other characters be handled other than letters? Can there be more whitespace between characters than a space?

Comment: You can clarify your question by changing your example to: `u = %q(a a b b c c a a)` and indicating whether the desired result is `a b c` or `a b c a`.  Please do this with an edit, rather than in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
u.tr(" ", "").squeeze.gsub(/(?<=.)(?=.)/, " ")
# => "a b c"
```

or

```
u.tr(" ", "").squeeze.gsub("", " ").strip
# => "a b c"
```

Comment: sawa, you can always be counted on to come up with something interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
u = %q(a a a a a b b b b c c c c)

u.gsub(/(.)( \1)+/, '\1')
#=> "a b c"
```

Comment: Nice, Stefan.  Best so far.

Comment: Perhaps `/(.)(\s+\1)+/` in case `u = %q(a a   a b b)`.  Not "best so far"; just "best".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

**Code**

```
u.split(' ').chunk {|c| c}.map(&:first).join(' ')
=> "a b c"
```

**Explanaton**

```
u = %q(a a a a a b b b b c c c c)
a = u.split(' ')
  #=> ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"]
b = a.chunk {|c| c}
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x000001010efe50>:each>
  b.to_a #=> [["a", ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a"]],
         #    ["b", ["b", "b", "b", "b"]],
         #    ["c", ["c", "c", "c", "c"]]]
c = b.map(&:first)
  #=> ["a", "b", "c"]
c.join(' ')
  #=> "a b c"
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way I can think of is this:

```
u = %q(a a a a a b b b b c c c c)
u.split.uniq.join(' ')
# => "a b c"
```

And **no regex** is always a nice bonus in my opinion ;)

Comment: I think the OP just wants to replace runs of the same character

Comment: I gave the answer based on space being the delimiter, but if it is by character, use `split('')` instead of `split`

Comment: your code would reduce `"a b a"` to `"a b"`